# Javascript remove element from DropDownListFor Razor MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, viewbag

I have this portion of file cshtml

```
<div class="fieldC" id="Cityzens1" style="">
            <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cityzenss1Cod, "Nationality 1")</div>
            <div class="field">
                
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cityzens1Cod, (SelectList)ViewBag.Cityzens)

            </div>
        </div>
```

I have to remove a specific value from the dropdown, I cannot do it upstream where I recover the values ​​from the database because for how the project is structured I would have to release the application, while doing it in the cshtml file in a Javascript script would be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following js(replace`{specific value}` to the special value which you want to remove):

```
 $(function () {
            $("#Cityzens1Cod option[value='{specific value}']").remove();    
        })
```